# Batch Windows: add quotes to all csv in all directories and subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to import in access a csv file I merged (and afterward rename) using the following sintax:

```
FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in ("*.csv") DO (
        copy /B *.csv merge.csv
    )
    POPD
)
```

Unfortunately access read both headers and field content ad headers because there is no text qualifier. So I tried adding quotes and it works.
My problem is that I have a lot of similar csv like this

```
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6|FIELD7|FIELD7|FIELD9|FIELD10|FIELD11|FIELD12|FIELD13|FIELD14|FIELD15
NAME|A|IT545454|M000000\ABCD|root/SERVER||SQL Service User|Enabled|05/05/2020|ADMIN(root\ADMINS)|ADMIN(root\ADMINS)
```

which need to be edited to look like this

```
"FIELD1"|"FIELD2"|"FIELD3"|"FIELD4"|"FIELD5"|"FIELD6"|"FIELD7"|"FIELD7"|"FIELD9"|"FIELD10"|"FIELD11"|"FIELD12"|"FIELD13"|"FIELD14"|"FIELD15
NAME"|"A"|"IT545454"|"M000000\ABCD"|"root/SERVER"|""|"SQL Service User"|"Enabled"|"05/05/2020"|"ADMIN(root\ADMINS)"|"ADMIN(root\ADMINS)"
```

My folder structure is like this.

```
MAIN DIRECTORY (where my batch should be)
--- FOLDER1
    --- SUBFOLDER1
        --- 1.CSV
        --- 2.CSV
    --- SUBFOLDER2
        --- 1.CSV
        --- 2.CSV
--- FOLDER2
    --- SUBFOLDER1
        --- 1.CSV
        --- 2.CSV
    --- SUBFOLDER2
        --- 1.CSV
        --- 2.CSV
```

Can anyone help?
Thank you

Comment: I gave you an answer yesterday, which can be easily amended to do this.

Comment: You are wanting to put a `"` at the beginning and end of each line, and to replace all `|` characters with `"|"`.

Comment: I'm trying to modify your code but I do not understand where I can work on the first line that you skip, if I also want to skip it to insert the grandparent folder name.

Comment: You're trying to modify whose code, @NickyNo, and from where?

Comment: @Compo I was commenting on Gerhard answer.

Comment: If you're trying to modify Gerhard's code from the previous day, why does your question include code which looks nothing like it. If you have an issue with code, and you don't show us the code, we cannot help you to fix an issue with it. As this is not a code request service, you must post the code you have written to achieve the task you've laid out in your question. The code you've posted does not attempt to exclude header lines, and it does not modify any content.

Comment: @Compo, as anyone can see the code I posted is the one I used to merge the files. I originally was thinking that I could work on that one, but then Gerhard commented that the code he submitted (as answer to another post of mine) could be useful and that I should work on that.I answered that I then would try and work on that code instead of the one I originally posted. You don't see that code because he did not post it again here, I assume because we already knew what he was talking about. So no reason to come at me this way and tell me that this is not a code request service, please.

Comment: It is your question, if you are working on code which is not performing the task you have written/modified it to perform, and you do not post it, we cannot help you to fix it. Future readers should not have to search under your name, locate your most recent question prior to this one, find an answer by Gerhard, and then guess what modifications you have made to that answer. Instead of manifesting an attack, take the [tour], and fully read [ask], including each of its linked pages. Once you've understood those, read your question as if you're a third party, and you may see exactly what I do!

Comment: @Compo I'm sorry but I'm not attacking anyone. Just asked a question, and gave explanation to you. I'm sorry if you feel attacked for that. I do not have produced code based on gerhards yet, so once I worked out this problem, I would simply post the code or my doubts on that, to help others solving the same issue, just as I've already done before with my other questions, so no problem for future readers ahead. As a third party I would never answer to someone as you did and as are you doing now. Please stop.

Comment: I didn't say you were attacking me, you specifically stated, it was I who "come at me this way".  Your question is off topic, if you don't want to be told that, and you have read the content as already advised, then delete your question, or update it to bring it on topic. I did not create the site guidelines, nor was I consulted on what is deemed an on topic and answerable question. You have provided a task, with before and after criteria, and no code to get from one to the other. There are several questions on this site which merge multiple `.csv` files whilst excluding duplicated headers.